# How to use case statement with select and group by

Tags: case

select company,
       case when ((select count(*) from ftmuser where active='0' group by company)>5) Then (select count(*) from ftmuser where active='0' group by company) 
       ELSE '0' 
       END
From ftmuser

I want to display only those records having count > 5 but above query fails and says ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

Please guide me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: you are returning more than one row due to group by in your select stmt. please elaborate on what are you trying to accomplish

Comment: I want to show company whose count is greater than 5 else show 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select company, case when ((select count(*) from ftmuser where active='0'
                            group by company where company=ft.company)>5)
                     Then (select count() from ftmuser <br>where active='0'
                           group by company where company=ft.company )
                     ELSE '0' END
From ftmuser ft
```